# parseFloat doesn't work and returns as NaN React

Tags: reactjs

So, I'm trying to do some calculations from the field i have taken from an input:

```js
const a = { 
price: '12',
qta: '2',
unit: '2',
total: '44' // I want to calculate this as * and put it here
}
```

So the problem is I'm taking as strings and I have to convert to number, I do use `parseFloat` for this as the following example:

```js
 const unit = parseFloat(temp[_index_p].unit);
 const hours = parseFloat(temp[_index_p].hours);
 const price = parseFloat(temp[_index_p].price);
 const newTotal = unit * price + hours * price;
       temp[_index_p] = {
        ...temp[_index_p],
         [property]: value,
          total: newTotal,
         };
       }
 setData({ ...data, parts: temp });
```

So that code is called on edit and the problem is something doesn't work and returns `NaN and not the wanted value.

// Ignore the index part because I'm editing multipy object, but consider it as one single object

Comment: Can you console log each of the data (unit, hours, price) and see which one may be problematic. Also console.log for us temp[_index_p] maybe the object is not as you think (includes comma or dots)

Comment: there is no `hours` attribute in your object and when you try to assign a property to a value to a variable `const hours = parseFloat(temp[_index_p].hours);`   it will be undefined and it will lead to `NaN` on ` const newTotal = unit * price + hours * price;
` this statement

Comment: @Sheri yes hahaha

Comment: But I have another problem now

Comment: The states doesn;t update

Comment: But aftert the second edit